# problem with validating regular expression using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm facing a problem with validating this regular expression. In fact, this function works like middleware to validate inputs from the user that accepts up to 2 decimal places after comma.

I need to allow for the following examples:

Pass:

- 1.12
- 10.15
- 20
- 14.1

Fail:

- 10.100
- 15,10
- 12e9
- Anything that has letters on it

My try :

```
const validation = (values) => {
  let errors = {};
  let commaValidation = new RegExp("^(\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2}))");
  for (var prop in values) {
    if (commaValidation.test(commaValidation.test(parseFloat(values[prop] && parseFloat(values[prop]) >= 0 && parseFloat(values[prop] <= 20))) ) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(values, prop)) {
        errors[prop] = "Entrez un nombre entre 0,00 et 20,00";
      }
    }
  }
  return errors;
};

export default validation;
```

Comment: You have to add an anchor `$` and make the decimal part optional `^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` https://regex101.com/r/T8NdAe/1

Comment: You also need to double escape the backslashes in the RegExp constructor, and for the match only you can omit the outer capturing group.

Comment: @Thefourthbird How can i add that ? cuz i'm new to the regex thing ?

Comment: Use `let commaValidation = new RegExp("^\\d{1,2}(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?$");` or just `let commaValidation = /^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/`

Comment: This regex should get work done `^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: Also it's better to use regex like: `let commaValidation = new RegExp(/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/);` with `/` slashes so you don't have to escape backslashes or things like that.